# can't copy objects into new array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array filled with objects of a type I have declared myself (called ServiceUnit). I now want to filter out only some of the objects from this array and what I'm doing to acheive this is that I have a new array with the correct size and just try to copy the objects in to the new one.

```
ServiceUnit[] serviceUnits = ProductConfiguration.ServiceGuide.GetServiceUnits();

ServiceUnitType serviceUnitType = ProductConfiguration.ServiceGuide.GetServiceUnitType(guid);
int size = 0;

/* COUNT THE NUMBER OF OBJECTS ADHERING TO MY CRITERIA */
foreach (ServiceUnit unit in serviceUnits)
{
    if (unit.ServiceUnitTypeAttributes[0].ServiceUnitType.Id == serviceUnitType.Id)
    {
        size++;
    }
}

/* ARRAY TO STORE FILTERED OBJECTS BASED ON A CRITERIA */
ServiceUnit[] serviceUnitsFiltered = new ServiceUnit[size];

/* LOOP AND CHECK IF ADHERING TO CRITERIA, THEN COPY TO NEW ARRAY */
for(int i=0; i<serviceUnits.Length; i++){
    if(serviceUnits[i].ServiceUnitTypeAttributes[0].ServiceUnitType == serviceUnitType){
        serviceUnitsFiltered[i] = serviceUnits[i];
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that the new array does have the right amount of objects in it, but they are not populated with the data from serviceUnits[i]. Instead they are just "nulled".

Any ideas on what might be wrong or how to solve it?

Comment: Aside from anything else, you appear to be filtering by two different criteria - your `if` conditions are different. Which one did you want?

Comment: To count you are comparing `Id`, while for filling you are comparing `ServiceUnitType` itself. Those check are not necessarily to be equal in terms of equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do...

```
ServiceUnit[] serviceUnits = ProductConfiguration.ServiceGuide.GetServiceUnits();

ServiceUnitType serviceUnitType = ProductConfiguration.ServiceGuide.GetServiceUnitType(guid);

serviceUnitsFiltered = serviceUnits.Where(unit=>unit.ServiceUnitTypeAttributes[0].ServiceUnitType.Id == serviceUnitType.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark, This solved the problem. It seems to be the same as Vilx- suggested but with unit instead of x which seems to have done the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: you can name "unit" what ever you like, its the equivalent of "foreach (ServiceUnit unit in serviceUnits)" in your code. LINQ expressions are incredibly powerful and can improve the readability and maintainability of your code.

Answer (score 2):

The bug is in this line:

```
serviceUnitsFiltered[i] = serviceUnits[i];
```

The index to `serviceUnitsFiltered` shouldn't be `i` but something else. Probably a new variable that is incremented every time you add something to `serviceUnitsFiltered`, like:

```
serviceUnitsFiltered[j++] = serviceUnits[i];
```

Also consider using LINQ, it's shorter (albeit a tiny bit slower):

```
serviceUnitsFiltered = serviceUnits.Where(x=>x.ServiceUnitTypeAttributes[0].ServiceUnitType == serviceUnitType).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks @Vilx- , Didn't work with using something other than i though. The linq solution seems like one that I would prefer though. Should that statement be just after I declare serviceUnitsFiltered array with a set size or? Tried it like that but I didn't get any objects in it.

Comment: @JonathanLind - the `ToArray()` method returns a new array. You don't need to allocate it beforehand (that just wastes memory, since you're throwing it out immediately). You should really read up on what is what, and also look **CAREFULLY** at your code. A few wrong symbols are easy to miss, but can create quite a havoc - like in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it much easier with LINQ:

```
serviceUnitsFiltered = serviceUnits.Where(su => su.ServiceUnitTypeAttributes[0].ServiceUnitType == serviceUnitType)
                                   .ToArray();
```

Comment: Compare their `Id`, seems that `if` produces some results, while without it you will always have empty sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List<T>` instead of using array :

```
/* LOOP AND CHECK IF ADHERING TO CRITERIA, THEN COPY TO NEW ARRAY */
List<ServiceUnit> serviceUnitsFiltered= new List<ServiceUnit>();

for(int i = 0; i < serviceUnits.Length; i++) 
    if(serviceUnits[i].ServiceUnitTypeAttributes[0].ServiceUnitType == serviceUnitType) 
       serviceUnitsFiltered.Add(serviceUnits[i]);
```

Or if you strictly need an array of ServiceUnit elements you can convert it using `List<T>.ToArray()` method

P.S.
LINQ is one line solution but it is slower than simple `for` loop with just one `if(condition)` expression...

Comment: Thanks @Fabjan for your reply. This didn't work for me (no objects were copied to the list) and I also need to have it as an Array for later use.

Comment: @JonathanLind that's strange because it uses the same condition that other answers here